# Test WebAPI on localhost but note resolving the address

Tags: asp.net

I'm currently testing a solution with on oneside a ASP.Net WebAPI and on the other hand a Xamarin application. 
Both are running on my machine for testing ...

I have an issue to have both working together on resolving the name of my machine (localhost)
The Web API is working fine. On the following address : http://localhost:50783/api/values/2

But if I use:

http://127.0.0.1:50783/api/values/2

It does not work.

I'm surprise about this. Thought this was the standard IP for the localhost. 
My hosts file is the following

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Comment: This may help:  
https://cyanbyfuchsia.wordpress.com/2014/07/29/make-iis-express-works-with-http127-0-0-1/

Comment: Is your Xamarin application running in an emulator?

Comment: Yes I ran my Xaramin App in the emulator. In the project the function Client.GetStringAsync is systematically resolving localhost to its IP address

Comment: @rad Your link sounds to be helpful but I cannot find in the <Site> my website name... There is the well a "WebSite1" but it is not mine. If I change well localhost to IP. this does not work either.

Comment: Also try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543443/cant-access-127-0-0-1

Comment: @rad thank you. I did find this before and tried... But again no success.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your web-api's bindings.

In Visual Studio → right click on your Project → Properties → choose Web → change the project URL to 127.0.0.1 (leave the port as is) → click on Create Virtual Directory and save the project.

[image: Project binding]

Comment: Thank you. This well force the project to start on this adress, but this does not help my problem with  IIS to be solve. the 127.0.0.1 is not working while localhost yes...

Comment: @JonathanHalleux, Another option would be editing the `applicationhost.config` file, which by deault located at `My Documents\IISExpress\config`. Find the `sites` section and edit the your project bindings as needed (replace `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`). restart your computer afterwards and try debugging again.

Comment: change `binding` node to: `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50783:127.0.0.1" />`

Comment: thank you. Tried to replace the line exactly as you propose but still the same... I restarted IIS service. But http://localhost:50783/ works, but http://127.0.0.1:50783/ still doesn't work. This makes me crazy... 
I tried also on two different computers and have the same issue on both...

Comment: @JonathanHalleux, very odd. It has some to do with IIS Express bindings. If I come up with a new idea I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try uncommenting

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
```

in the hosts file by removing the **#** from the beginning of that.

Comment: Update the file and reboot the computer... Still the same.