# Domain name is not loading the response but localhost works

Tags: windows, hosts-file, mountebank

I am using mountebank for mocking responses which is running in Docker on port 2525. Stubs are created on port 443. The response is successful when I use localhost but not with the domain name. The domain names are redirected in hosts file.

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Failed to hit mock with the domain name

[Hosts File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lSIA.png)

[Postman console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsL3s.png)

[Wireshark log for the domain name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keB4s.png)

Successful localhost logs which uses IPV6 internally

[Postman Successful Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RicuC.png)

[Successful response console details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov5SS.png)

[Wireshark logs for localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Toz1u.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! We would love to help you, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: This issue is resolved by redirecting all domain names to ipv6 address

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by redirecting all domain names to ipv6 address.
Also listening to ipv6 address using netsh command. Referred to [Can't access 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543443/cant-access-127-0-0-1)

```
netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1
```