# Unable to replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 in URL

Tags: http, localhost, .net-6.0, iis-express, asp.net-4.8

I have two local apps running:

- ASP.NET client (ASP.NET 4.8): `https://localhost:44300`
- Duende Identity Server (.NET 6): `https://localhost:44349`

The Identity Server cookies are being sent to the client application when the browser makes request to the client application.

Since this wouldn't happen in prod due to them being two different URLs, I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16328311/2063755) which says to use one as `127.0.0.1`, and the other as `localhost`, in order to replicate how the cookies would be sent in prod.

However, when I try to access `https://127.0.0.1:44300`, I get `Bad Request - Invalid Hostname`.

I've checked `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and can see it has these two lines:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

I've also tried the suggestions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34551690/2063755), but it didn't work.

How can I access `localhost` using `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: If you learn more about your IIS Express configuration and the site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background then the answer shouldn't be hard to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goal was to replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 in the URL.
Originally I was getting `Bad Request - Invalid Hostname`

This worked for me (Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current - Version 17.6.4)

Run cmd as admin and run these commands:

```
netsh http add urlacl url="https://*:portnumber/" user=everyone
netsh http add urlacl url="https://localhost:portnumber/" user=everyone
```

Make a backup of `\.vs\config\applicationhost.config`.

Edit `\.vs\config\applicationhost.config` to have this in your app's bindings section:

```
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:localhost" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:*" />
```

Make sure it's listed in that order.

Run VS as admin, and you should be able to go to `https://127.0.0.1:portnumber`.

I've written about this [here](https://davidklempfner.medium.com/be-careful-running-multiple-localhost-apps-8e69e0a0293b?sk=bc0ce58ec76202ed8e52291425439b2b).